# Syncing contacts with google contacts using contacts javascript api

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api

Hello I have a web portal and people would share there email id's. I would to add the sync with google contacts. I am using javascript api for that, but facing lot of problems. I tried the example code provided by google http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/1.0/developers_guide_js.html#Interactive_Samples
First I need to authenticate users to access there gmail id, i used this code

```
var contactsService;

function setupContactsService() {
  contactsService = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactsService('exampleCo-exampleApp-1.0');
}

function logMeIn() {
  var scope = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds';
  var token = google.accounts.user.login(scope);
}

function initFunc() {
  setupContactsService();
  logMeIn();
  getMyContacts();
}
```

But the problem is I am able to see the google authentication page when I click on the grant access button,I am redirected to same authentication page though I included create contact function and called on click. I am not able to figure how to proceed further and send contact details dynamically to gmail.

Kindly help me out

Comment: Did you make sure you get the token after you get back from "grant access" page?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem what I followed was I created a iFrame and adding all the javascript and HTML inside that iframe and place that iframe in the mail page.